# How to avoid: Negative damage is healing the enemy?

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and want to program a simple simulation where two monsters are going to battle each other in console.

I have one problem which I can't figure out, how to avoid it.
The problem is, if the AttackPower is lower than the DefensivePower, the value will be negative and starts healing the enemy, because negative & negative = positive.

```
do
{
    if (currentFighter == 0)
    {
        s_monsters[1].m_Health -= 
            s_monsters[0].m_AttackPower - s_monsters[1].m_DefensivePower;
    }
    else
    {
        s_monsters[0].m_Health -= 
            s_monsters[1].m_AttackPower - s_monsters[0].m_DefensivePower;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add an if statement somewhere that sets the value to 0 if it is less than 0.

Comment: So what do you want to do? Be specific. Let's see some examples and what you've tried thus far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `Math.Max` (which returns the higher of two numbers), such as:

```
s_monsters[1].m_Health -= Math.Max(s_monsters[0].m_AttackPower - s_monsters[1].m_DefensivePower, 0);
```

In this case, if *attack power* is less than *defensive power*, the attack would have no effect.

Comment: Nice, and inline too. I dig it more than the solution I was going to post.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to assign `s_monsters[1].m_AttackPower - s_monsters[0].m_DefensivePower` to a variable of its own and run a check to detect whether or not it is less than zero, if the statement returns true, set the variable to 0.

You can then inject the new variable where `s_monsters[1].m_AttackPower - s_monsters[0].m_DefensivePower` is now and your problem should cease to exist.

```
do
{
 double attackDamage;
 if (currentFighter == 0)
 {
    attackDamage = s_monsters[0].m_AttackPower - s_monsters[1].m_DefensivePower
    s_monsters[1].m_Health -= ((attackDamage < 0) ? 0 : attackDamage);
 }
 else
 {
    attackDamage = s_monsters[1].m_AttackPower - s_monsters[0].m_DefensivePower
    s_monsters[0].m_Health -= ((attackDamage < 0) ? 0 : attackDamage);
 }
}
```

Though I definitely recommend using Mike C.'s inline method for readability, file size, and scope pollution concerns.